# Troubles with Promises and Fetches

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I've started to study React and have some troubles with Promises.

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3)
  }, 2000);
})

p1
  .then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // First block
      console.log("This was executed.")
    }, 1000)
  })
  .then(() => {
      // Second block
    console.log("This block is executed too.");
  })
```

With tthe following code, how can I execute first the first block and after, the second block?

Comment: `return` from the first block

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise in the first `then` block as well

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(3)
  }, 2000);
})

p1
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // First block
          console.log("This was executed.")
          resolve();
        }, 1000)
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
      // Second block
    console.log("This block is executed too.");
  })
```

Comment: can you explain me the reason?

Comment: The code inside the `then` is asynchronous, so if you want the second `then` to wait for the `setTimeout` to resolve, then you need to tell it to do so as you did for the first function call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function p1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //add return
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3)
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

or with es6

```js
const p1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //add return
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3)
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

Comment: yep, just noticed that... the edit should be correct thanks @Utkanos

Answer (score 0):

Its already execute the first block first
because of async nature of setTimeout, it will execute next call here then().
to execute your first block you have to add a promise.

```
    var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(3)
    }, 2000);
});

function firstCall() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("This was executed.");
            resolve(true)
        }, 1000);
    })
}

p1
    .then(firstCall)
    .then(() => {
        // Second block
        console.log("This block is executed too.");
    })
```